# How to get value of a key using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects. suppose if i  know the value of key3.

```
key3= value3. How to get value of key1 that matches to specific array.
output: value1


[{
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4'
},

{
    'key1': 'value5',
    'key2': 'value6',
    'key3': 'value7',
    'key4': 'value8'
}]
```

Comment: please add the result, you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 array.find(it => it.key3 === "value3").key1
```

Comment: Hi @Jonas Wilms, what is significant of key1

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda OP is asking for it. The question is (paraphrased) "If I know the value of `key3`, how can I get the value of `key1`".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more advanced version, using [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const data=[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3','key4':'value4'},{'key1':'value5','key2':'value6','key3':'value7','key4':'value8'}];

const {key1} = data.find(({key3})=>key3==='value3');

console.log(key1);
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: key3 is not defined`. And I'm not sure how is destructuring any better than directly getting the value.

Comment: @VLAZ forgot to update my console.log . It's a modern approach of retrieving object /array specific values. If the value is *known* to exist then this is better, otherwise the other approach (`find().key1 || null`) would be better.

Comment: If you want a fallback value, you can still do the same here `const {key1 = "defaultValue"} = someObject`. A double null-safe-fallback would be `const {key1 = "defaultValue"} = someObject || {}`. But to me it seems more of a bother than just going `.key1`. If you need to fetch several keys, then destructuring might be better. In general the "do this!" types of answers that offer no explanation *why* you'd want to do it are more noise than help.